# Error handling with assert

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

Suppose I have a class.
I want to give an error in `init` if my class doesn't follow the described rule

```
class Puzzle {

var puzzle_array: [Int]
var zero_index: Int

public init(array: [Int]) {
    assert(array.count == 9, "Array should be lenght 9")
    assert(array.index(of: 0) != nil, "There should ne 0 in array")
    puzzle_array = array
    zero_index = puzzle_array.index(of: 0)!
}
}
```

Then I need to create several instances of this class in a loop. Some of them, won't satisfy the condition, I described in `init` and complier and I will get an error. 
But what I want is to skip creation of this instances without executing an error. And I want to keep checking condition logic inside `init`.

My initial idea might be wrong, but I'll appreciate if you help me to make it more properly.

Comment: You want to show error or just check if condition not passed not create instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [failable initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) to accomplish this, your object will be nil if you don't satisfy your checks.

```
class Puzzle {
  var puzzle_array: [Int]
  var zero_index: Int

  public init?(array: [Int]) {
    guard array.count == 9, array.index(of: 0) != nil else {
      return nil
    }

    puzzle_array = array
    zero_index = puzzle_array.index(of: 0)!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @colmg that you should use `failable initialiser`, because it's destroys information about what actually went wrong.

Instead you should use [`throwable initalizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html):

```
class Puzzle {
    var puzzle_array: [Int]
    var zero_index: Int

    public init(array: [Int]) throws {
        try assert(array.count == 9, "Array should be lenght 9")
        try assert(array.index(of: 0) != nil, "There should ne 0 in array")
        puzzle_array = array
        zero_index = puzzle_array.index(of: 0)!
    }
}
```

Assuming that `assert` is not standard version here, but this function:

```
struct AssertError: Error {
    let description: String
}

func assert(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ description: String) throws {
    if !condition() {
        throw AssertError(description: description)
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
do {
   let puzzle = try Puzzle([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
} catch let error {
   // Here you can handle error, and see what exactly went wrong, instead of just knowing that initialisation failed
}
```

Or you can use more advanced version:

```
func assert(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ error: Error) throws {
    if !condition() {
        throw error
    }
}

class Puzzle {
    var puzzle_array: [Int]
    var zero_index: Int

    public init(array: [Int]) throws {
        try assert(array.count == 9, PuzzleError.invalidArrayLength)
        try assert(array.index(of: 0) != nil, PuzzleError.arrayContainsZero)
        puzzle_array = array
        zero_index = puzzle_array.index(of: 0)!
    }

    enum PuzzleError: Error {
        case invalidArrayLength
        case noZeroInArray
    }
}
```